# Name of animated series with enemies being half brothers

Tags: story-identification

I am looking for an animated series I watched when I was little, beginning of the 2000's. I think it was on one of the channels offered by Canal+ (French encrypted television channel).

It was a western-style animated series, in a post-apocalyptic setting. For all the following points, I am not sure if they are true or not, as I was quite young:

- the hero is a badass guy that flies a red plane;
- he is recruited/asked/? by the city of the good people;
- the prince of this city looks very similar as the prince of the city of evil people;
- it is revealed later that they have the same mother, and are half-brothers;
- the king/chief/? of the evil people has orange or yellow eyes.

I am not sure anymore for any of this and every time I ask around, nobody knows about this series.

Comment: I came here thinkign this as *Inuyasha* -- nope, wrong pair of half brothers.

Comment: When was it airing, or better, when was it _produced_? Was it translated or possibly a French production? Any of the French voices reminded you of other French-dubbed characters?

Comment: I edited the question. It was in the beginning of the 2000's. As for the voices/dubs, honestly I have no idea. I was like 6 year old at the time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Possibly Chris Colorado, there seems to be a lot of similarities with what you have mentioned.

[image: Chris Colorado]

> I watched when I was little, beginning of the 2000's. I think it was
>   on one of the channels offered by Canal+

First aired on Canal+ in 2000.

> It was a western-style animated series, in a post-apocalyptic setting.

It was set after a meteor strike destroyed most of civilisation.

> the hero is a badass guy that flies a red plane

Well white and red.

> he is recruited/asked/? by the city of the good people

He is.

> the prince of this city looks very similar as the prince of the city
>   of evil people

Nope. But, there is a general type character who works for the bad guys and is very similar in appearance to the title character.

> it is revealed later that they have the same mother, and are
>   half-brothers

OK, I'm going to pass on this one. I know there was a weird connection between the title character's recently discovered half-sister and someone who defected to the evil side many years ago. So...maybe?

> the king/chief/? of the evil people has orange or yellow eyes.

The main bad guy in this had a glowing red visor thing going on.

Comment: Yes! That is the one! Thanks a lot! Apparently I just imagined the half-brother thing yes.